# Determine the number of days in a month

Tags: c

I am receiving the **year**, **month** and **day** as inputs and I am trying to validate the inputs in an efficient way. The **year** range is [0-99] (0,4,8.. are considered leap years), **month** range [1-12] and **day** range [1-31].

The straight forward way of validating the day would be the following:

```
if( (Day<1u) || (Day>31u) ){
    /*error*/
}
else if ( (Month==4u) || (Month==6u) || (Month==9u) || (Month==11u) && (Day>30u) ){
    /*error*/
}
else if ( (Month==2u) && (Year % 4u == 0u) && (Day > 29u) ){
    /*error*/
}
else if ( (Month==2u) && (Year % 4u != 0u) && (Day > 28u) ){
    /*error*/
}
else
{
    /*valid*/
}
```

But it has a high complexity.

A lookup table seems like a better choice. And now the question:

**Is there a more efficient way of creating the table for this case other than the following?**

```
const int testTable[4][12] = {
    {31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
    {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
    {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
    {31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
};

if( testTable[ Year % 4 ][ Month - 1 ] >= Day){
    /*valid*/
}
else{
    /*error*/
}
```

Is there another rule that I'm not seeing?

Comment: What does this have to do with embedded systems? I'll remove the tag.

Comment: Have you forgotten the lessons of Y2K already?  Or were you not around when that happened?  Using two digits for the year is a recipe for unhappiness in the long run.  For instance, the 2100 is not a leap year, and neither was 1900, though 2000 was.  For pity's sake, use 4-digit years!

Comment: To make it worse, you need to account for years divisible by 100, then again by 400.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler I didn't made the constraints I just have to follow them :)

Comment: Relay the reminder to the powers-that-be.  It probably won't have any effect, but you can but try.  It is distressing that people are falling into the bad habits of the pre-95 coding teams just a decade and a half after a major code cleanup exercise.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need one dimension for leap years and another one for non leap years:

```
int isleap(int year)
{
    return (year % 4 == 0 && year % 100 != 0) || (year % 400 == 0);
}

int mthdays(int month, int year)
{
    static const int days[2][13] = {
        {0, 31, 28, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31},
        {0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
    };
    int leap = isleap(year);

    return days[leap][month];
}
```

> The year range is [0-99] (0,4,8.. are considered leap years)

Then your `isleap()` function must be:

```
int isleap(int year)
{
    return (year % 4 == 0);
}
```

> month range [1-12]

Using:

```
{0, 31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
```

instead of

```
{31, 29, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31, 31, 30, 31, 30, 31}
```

you can avoid `[ Month - 1 ]`

Comment: Agreed, but with 2 dimensions I need an extra function call or an extra check.

Comment: Note that you could use (unsigned) `char` to store the numbers, saving space.  You can make `isleap()` into a `static inline` function and the compiler will almost certainly inline it, especially the simpler version (which might be modified to `return ((year & 0x3) == 0);` by the compiler to avoid actual division, especially if you use `unsigned` for the `year`, which tells the compiler it doesn't have to fret about negative values.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, you are right about the `unsigned` type, but in real world we normally use `signed int`, once I had to use `glib` (where params for [date and time](https://developer.gnome.org/glib/stable/glib-Date-and-Time-Functions.html) are typedefed to `guint16`) and the code almost always needed a cast.

Comment: surely `Month - 1` is preferable to wasting 2 ints worth of storage space

Comment: @M.M, even if `days` is `static`?  it exists for the entire life of the program and is initialized only once, isn't it?

Answer (score 2):

How about calculating the number of days in a few operations like this:

```
int DaysInMonth(int month, int year)
{
    int days = 30 + ((month + (month >> 3)) & 1);
    if (month == 2)
        days -= IsLeapYear(year) ? 1 : 2;
    return days;
}
```

The IsLeapYear check is only performed in February, making this quite efficient for 11 of the 12 months, without the need for a memory access for the array lookup others proposed.

The above calculation works like this :

Start out with 30 days, and initially add 1 for odd numbered months, by anding the month with 1.
This adds 1 for January, March, May, July (further than that is explained below) and adds 0 to February (a special case explained below), April, June, etc.

However, the "knuckle pattern" swaps at the 8th month (so that next to July, August also is 31 days and from there, short and long and months repeat again).

To cater for that switch, I make sure to invert the addition of 1 or 0 by adding the bit that represents August (month 8, being the 4rd bit from the right) into the mask, shifted 3 bits to the right.
Doing that, the month value I use as an intermediate "day correction" gets increased by zero for month 1 to 7, and by 1 for months 8 to 12 (turning those into 9 upto 13).
This has the effect that after odd-numbered July (which produces 31) August also becomes odd-numbered internally, and will also produce 31 days!

What remains is to special-case February, which is an even-numbered month so has 30 days until this point. I correct this by subtracting 1 or 2 depending whether it's a leap year or not, changing February into 29 or 28 days.

This way, the returned resulting number of days for any month in any year is correctly calculated with only a few operations and no memory access for table lookups!

Simple, really ;)

Comment: Nice. :-) Tested and... I like it...